# disptach action error, value appearing as nested object

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am dispatching an action:

```
  removeAchievement(achievement){
        this.props.removeAchievement({
           type: 'REMOVE_ACHIEVEMENT',
            id: this.props.day.id,
            text: achievement,
    })
  }
```

Action creator:

```
export const removeAchievement = (id, text) => ({ type: types.REMOVE_ACHIEVEMENT, id, text })
```

However in my reducer, the data appears nested in my id as this:

[image]

How can stop it being nested?

Comment: If you `console.log` the `this.props.day.id` in your component before you dispatch, what do you get?

Comment: Show us the `removeAchievement` action creator.

Comment: Updated question

Comment: @HenrikAndersson outputs 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your action creator is expecting an id and text, but you're calling it with the whole object --

```
this.props.removeAchievement({
           type: 'REMOVE_ACHIEVEMENT',
            id: this.props.day.id,
            text: achievement,
    })
```

Call it with the id and text instead --

```
this.props.removeAchievement(this.props.day.id, achievement);
```